# Remote Desktop with Windows Azure Preview

Tags: azure, remote-desktop

I am running a website on the Window Azure preview portal and I am trying to connect via remote desktop. I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and the way you publish a website to Azure has changed slightly.

Normally I would connect to a cloud services role and enable remote desktop that way. However I am running two websites and no cloud service so I cant seem to find the option anywhere!

[image: Windows Azure Remote Desktop]

I have tried the following links on the windowsazure.com site with no luck:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/remote-desktop/

I have also tried going to the old portal to enable remote desktop but it seems as if the option is greyed out. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, and According to http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/how-choose-windows-azure, you can't connect to a Web Site (as opposed to Web Role) with RDS.

Comment: So it seems as if there might be no access with RDS to websites. Any idea if I can switch to a web role within preview mode?

Comment: I think you can always run a web role, but I don't know exactly what kind of free/preview offer you've got, or how that will carry over.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to remote desktop into your websites or cloud services? If it's websites, I don't think you can because it normally runs in a shared environment i.e. in one VM many websites are hosted where as in Cloud Services, you get a dedicated VM for your application.

Comment: Ah okay, its just that I am running a reserved instance, so I thought that I would be able to remote into the environment that the websites are on?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a web role with Preview Mode, which will create your Cloud Service and give you Remote access. This is easily done with Visual Studio 2012 by right clicking on the Porject and selecting "Add Windows Azure Cloud Services Project".

Comment: All I see in Visual Studio under Cloud is "Get Windows Azure SDK for .NET". There is no option for "Add Windows Azure Cloud Services Project"

Comment: Get the SDK then the option should present itself